# How to use PHP to apply a CSS class based on an inconsistent pattern of image tiles?

Tags: php, wordpress, modulus

I am displaying posts one week at a time and each of the respective days for that particular week will contain thumbnail images for each individual post. The goal of the feed will look something like the screenshot diagram below (the brackets indicate a post with it's respective post count.)

As you can see I produce an uneven number of posts on a daily basis. There's no way of me knowing how many post I'll publish. I would like to be able to apply a CSS class (in the code snippet below you'll see I call the CSS class "margin") and this will be used in my CSS so I can apply margin to all center images.

Each row in the diagram has AT MOST 3 images across (i.e. 3 columns: left, middle, right); however it can have an unlimited number of rows down. I would like to be able to apply this "margin" class to all posts in the middle column.

I began to code up how this gets accomplished but what I can't figure out is how to apply the class only to all middle posts. A friend told me to use modulus, but can't figure how to implement it properly. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

**Please see this screenshot of diagram I made to help depict what I am looking to achieve. I think this will help you understand the question better:**

[image: Post digram]

```
<section class="post-by-date">
<?php 
    $day_check = '';
    $today = get_the_date();
    $year = date('Y');
    $week = date('W');
    $news_query = new WP_Query('category_name=main&year=' . $year . '&w=' . $week);

    while ($news_query->have_posts()) : $news_query->the_post();
    $day = get_the_date('j');
    if ($day != $day_check) {
        echo "<h3>" . get_the_date() . "</h3>";
    }

    $post_count = $news_query->current_post;
    $found_posts = $news_query->found_posts;

    if ($post_count % 3 == 0) {
        $apply_css_margin = TRUE;

    }
    else {
        $apply_css_margin = FALSE;
    }

?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php if($apply_css_margin) { post_class('margin'); } else { post_class(); } ?>>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?>
    </a>
</article>
<?php $day_check = $day; endwhile; ?>
</section>
```

Comment: Without a careful look, it seems like you are taking the right general approach but would want `$post_count % 3 == 2` instead since you want the middle one

Comment: Also, it is considered best practice not to include formatting in CSS class names, and even better in this case, since the order can be determined by mechanisms understood by CSS, if you don't care about supporting IE8, you can use something like `section.post-by-date > article:nth-child(2) {font-style:italic;}` and avoid adding a class altogether.

Comment: @BrettZamir - I actually initially tried using nth-child; however, the the issue comes into play as there are an uneven number of posts published on a daily basis. So nth-child will typically work for a period of time, but when I scroll down the list, eventually the pattern breaks so this doesn't seem to be possible...

Comment: Even if you use `3n+2` as the expression (which I should have posted above)? If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what you're doing (and `3n+2` also fits with my `$post_count %3 == 2` suggestion above).

Comment: @BrettZamir - just tried using nth-child(3n+2), but that doesn't seem to fit the pattern...I updated a screenshot above of what a post layout could look like. As you see this scenario (since I'm only showing 1 weeks were of posts) could be any sort of pattern - depends on how many posts I publish that day.

Comment: Did you include nth-child(3n+2) within `section.post-by-date > article:nth-child(2) {font-style:italic;}`? It needs to be relative to the section. If it is, then 3n+2 means "starting with the second post, every 3 after that within the section will also be marked". Also, I presume you are using the CSS I mentioned WITHOUT the "margin" CSS?

Comment: @BrettZamir - yep, i'm not using the "margin" CSS at all. I just tried  your nth-child method and didn't get it to fit the pattern...